# SQL Server CE 3.5/MS Sync Upgrade path

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce, synchronization

First off, I'm hoping that I can word this question in a way that it is an OK question for here. I have an occasionally connected application which I basically sync to a remote server when the program starts up, then again when it closes.

I have been using SQL Server CE 3.5 with the Microsoft Sync framework, but that appears to have been discontinued by Microsoft in SQL Server CE 4.0 (Yes, I know I am behind the times here, but I am just getting around to doing some major overhauls to the program).

I have been searching for the "Official" upgrade path, and the only solutions which I can find appear to revolve around SQL Azure which is not an option here. Are there any good options here for an upgrade path? I don't have control over the DB server here, and I am hearing rumors that they are in the early planning stages of an upgrade to SQL Server 2012 which would break my application as it stands.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL CE 4 with sync fx as desctibed here, via a binding redirect http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2012/04/20/sync-framework-and-sql-compact-4-yes-you-can/